# Linker command failed, with PubNub library in swift with static framework

Tags: iphone, xcode, swift, linker-errors, pubnub

I am using xcode 7.3 and using PubNub library. The build runs fine on simulator but fails while running on actual device.
Here is the error that I see :

***ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/supercomputer/Documents/SitbaqApp/iPhoneDriverApp/CocoaLumberjack.framework/CocoaLumberjack, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/supercomputer/Documents/SitbaqApp/iPhoneDriverApp/CocoaLumberjack.framework/CocoaLumberjack (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/supercomputer/Documents/SitbaqApp/iPhoneDriverApp/PubNub.framework/PubNub, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/supercomputer/Documents/SitbaqApp/iPhoneDriverApp/PubNub.framework/PubNub (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PubNub", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.PubNub in AppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_PNConfiguration", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.PNConfiguration in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)***

I have the $(inherited) flag in the OTHER LINKER FLAGS. I am not using cocoa pods for pubnub. It is framework drag and drop.

Now I am unable to run the app on actual device.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue but when i use `pod` so i solved this issue. pod get automatic dependancy.

[pod setup.](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/swift/pubnub-swift-sdk#how_to_get_it)

Comment: Always first find if library provide pod then must be use pod.